# Can't access my router settings page after changing channel

Tags: router

I was playing around with my router settings and changed the channel to auto and now I cannot access the settings from the IP. Any fix for this? The router is the Asus AC1300. The network associated with the router still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the router and try again accessing the setup page using the IP address of the setup page (nominally 192.168.1.1 or what you set it to).

If that does not work, reset the router to factory specs and set it up again.

[Reset ASUS Router](https://support.myrepublic.com.sg/hc/en-us/articles/360009269054-How-to-hard-reset-my-ASUS-router-)

> Use a pin or sharp-pointed pen to press and hold on the reset button
> for about 10-15 seconds The power indicator should start to flash upon
> successful reset During the hard reset, the only power light will be
> on and after 1-2mins the other lights will be back on. Ideally, there
> should be at least 4 lights must be on: Power, Internet (Globe icon),
> 2.4GHz and 5GHz.